# Проблема с 8080 портом после отключения электроэнергии

Tags: java, apache

У меня не стартуют никакие приложения через InteliJIdea корторые должны стартовать на `8080`. Все работало привильно до внезапного отключения электроэнергии, сразу после включения все попытки запустить приводят к :

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Embedded servlet container failed to start. Port 8080 was already in use.

Action:

Identify and stop the process that's listening on port 8080 or configure this application to listen on another port.

2017-10-13 15:31:31.777  INFO 4164 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@8a589a2: startup date [Fri Oct 13 15:31:26 MSK 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-10-13 15:31:31.779  INFO 4164 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2017-10-13 15:31:31.781  INFO 4164 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'getTaskExecutor'
```

При обращении к `localhost:8080`

```
Apache - version 2.4.27 
Server is up and running 
The default Apache context is www in the Apache installation folder
```

Приходится все время переключать на другой порт.

Я так понимаю что `Apache` и занимает. Как поправить эту проблему? Как остановить `Apache` и сделать так что бы каждый раз при запуске машины он не стартовал. Как было раньше до аварии. Я на Windows 10. Спасибо.

Comment: найти апач в сервисах и сделать его не стартуемым при старте системы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Самое простое в Автозагрузку добавить запуск файла shutdown.bat из каталога TOMCAT.
- Сложнее остановит сервис TOMCAT и перевести его в ручную загрузку.
- Если нужно просто освободить порт 8080 то он указан в файле конфигурации. Там его можно поменять.

Comment: добавить в автозагрузку  shutdown.bat???

Comment: @KoVadim автоотгрузку

Comment: После старта, что бы он сам отключился. Это для "домохозяек", но работает. И всегда можно востановить.

Comment: А вы думаете домохозяйка не может зайти в панели управления в сервисы и выключить автозапуск апача ? проще уж направить именно по этому пути, там кликов даже меньше, чем разыскивать нужный .bat

Comment: домохозяйка будет ставить апач и запускать InteliJIdea?